# Реализация Mutex без API операционной системы

Tags: c++, winapi, c++11, posix, mutex

Не понимаю по какой именно причине, такая реализация класса Mutex не корректна..

```
#define INLINE inline __attribute__((always_inline))
#ifdef __WIN32__
typedef DWORD ThreadIdType;
#endif

INLINE ThreadIdType GetThreadId()
{
#ifdef __WIN32__
    return GetCurrentThreadId();
#endif
}

class Mutex
{
private:

    bool lock;
    ThreadIdType thId;

    const bool Locking(const bool& val)
    {
        if(val)
        {
            if(lock)
            {
                while(lock);
                lock = true;
                thId = GetThreadId();
            }
            else
            {
                lock = true;
                thId = GetThreadId();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if(GetThreadId() == thId)
            {
                lock = false;
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

public:

    constexpr Mutex() : lock(false), thId(0) { }
    Mutex(const Mutex&) = delete;
    Mutex(Mutex&&)      = delete;

    INLINE void Lock()
    {
        Locking(true);
    }

    INLINE const bool Unlock()
    {
        return Locking(false);
    }
};
```

Насколько я понимаю вызова Lock и Unlock одновременно произойти не может.
В чём тогда может возникнуть проблема?
Тесты вроде бы проходит, но реализация этого объекта со стороны WinAPI, Posix и прочих, сильно смущает.
О многочисленных реализациях в курсе. Пишу велосипеды в целях обучения. :3

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Во-первых, с чего вы взяли что вызова Lock и Unlock одновременно произойти не может? Может, как и два Lock одновременно. Главная проблема - два потока могут одновременно проверить переменную `lock`, до того как успеют ее изменить. Сами подумайте, к чему это приведет.

Во-вторых, посмотрите на вот эту строчку: `while(lock);` Эта строчка впустую жрет процессорное время. В то же время, потоки, заблокированные на системных мьютексах, процессора не требуют.

Запустите диспетчер задач и посмотрите сколько процессов запущено. Если бы они все пользовались активным ожиданием - компьютер бы у вас просто висел.

В-третьих, оптимизатор имеет право заменить цикл `while(lock);` на `while(true);` потому что переменная `lock` в этом месте программы равна `true` и внутри цикла не меняется. Кстати, поскольку бесконечный цикл - UB (undefined behavior), оптимизатор может отсюда сделать вывод что `lock == false` и выкинуть "прямую" ветку условного оператора вообще.

Comment: 1) Где-то вычитал что вызов одной и той же функции класса одновременно из двух разных потоков невозможен.. Не могли бы подсказать что почитать на эту тему? (полагаю что-то близкое к асму?)
2) Совершенно точно, тупо не подумал, благодарю.
3) Оптимизацией не пользуюсь.

Comment: @Dylan993 *"Где-то вычитал что вызов одной и той же функции класса одновременно из двух разных потоков невозможен..."* Не читайте там больше ничего.

Comment: @Dylan993 *"Оптимизацией не пользуюсь"* а зря

Answer (score 4):

На некоторых архитектрурах присваивание может происходить не атомарно (попробуйте на восьмибитной AVR записать 4 байта одной инструкцией - фиг вам).

Одно ядро процессора может совершенно не ведать, что творит с переменной другое ядро, так как кэш у ядер - персональный, и без твердого указания этот кеш дернуть (барьер памяти, называется), синхронизации не будет.

Итого - для написания своих примитивов синхронизации нужно иметь экспертные знания по архитектуре процессора, компилятора и используемой операционной системе. Иначе наделаете элементарных ошибок, а мы будем ржать всем офисом.

Answer (score 4):

Ваша реализация похожа на spinlock, а не mutex. Тем не менее, чтобы сделать её корректной(хоть и малоэффективной) нужно изменить тип `lock` c `bool` на `std::atomic_bool` и немного поменять цикл:

```
bool Locking(bool val)
{
    if(val)
    {
        while(lock);
        bool expected = false;
        if(lock.compare_exchange_strong(expected, true))
            thId = GetThreadId();
        return true;
    }
    if(GetThreadId() == thId)
    {
        lock = false;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Без использования атомарного типа, не происходит никакого упорядочивания, а без него нельзя написать синхронизирующего примитива. Вы пытаетесь разбираться в довольно сложной теме, видимо, совершенно без знаний. Рекомендую почитать мой цикл статей по [многопоточности](http://scrutator.me/post/2012/04/04/parallel-world-p1.aspx) в C++, только знайте — это очень сложная тема и, возможно, Вам пока не стоит в неё погружаться.

Comment: Хм, а не вызывает ли `atomic_bool` под капотом синхронизационные функции ОС?

Comment: Хотя барьеры и всё такое по идее реализуемо и без ОС.

Comment: @VladD, Зависит от ОС и архитектуры, самом собой. Лично мне не известны такие архитектуры, где нужны блокировки для записи/чтения `bool`

Comment: @VladD, барьеры само собой используются, без них это нереализуемо. Барьеры это уровень процессорный, а не ОС.